# How to find out which Hugo theme was used in a Blog

Tags: blogging

Recently, I am seeing many blogs of which I like their themes (template). But I wonder which template they use. For example, there is a blog (https://sam217pa.github.io) created by using Hugo Template. One way is to go Hugo site (https://themes.gohugo.io/) and find out the similar template by visually.

I wonder there is way to find out the template by looking its source code (https://github.com/sam217pa/sam217pa.github.io).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by looking at the css files as this sets the theme styles. For your example, the css file css/solarized-light.min.css shows the comment:

"Orginal Style from ethanschoonover.com/solarized"

So this is the style used: ethanschoonover.com/solarized/

Of course if the site removes the original comments, you would be stumped!